# Not able to capture with capture groups

Tags: regex, powershell, match, capture-group

Within each text file, being worked with, there are two pages of listings. They are referenced identically using the same reference numbers (001,002, ... etc) The aim is to separate these two listings and store separately in an array. I have simplified the problem for testing.

```
# short listings (an unhelpful text file listing structure. But ain't that life? )
# "001 First in listing one 002 Second in listing one 003 Third in listing one 001 First in listing two 002 Second in listing two 003 Third in listing two

# read shortListings from file 
$listings = Get-Content -Path C:\test\test6\shortListings.txt
[string[]]$result = $null

# regular expression where I am trying to separate listing 'ones' & listing 'twos' into string array $result 

# $result[0] = "001 First in listing one 002 Second in listing one 003 Third in listing one"
# $result[1] = "001 First in listing two 002 Second in listing two 003 Third in listing two"

$regex = '(?s)(001.*?)((?=001.*?))'

$result = $listings | Select-String -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value}

# Okay. That's listing one. But how do I get listing two?
$result[0]
```

This is close [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/jcjarB/1) Listings 'two' string can be accessed via `$2`. But `$1` just gives both listings. I'm thinking these are referred as regex [backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) I have used them in Powershell to make replacements. Directly referencing the capture groups. For example:

```
-CReplace "([A-Z])\'.\s*([A-Z][a-z])",'$1 $2'
```

But not when accessing Powershell Object Match Values. If anyone can suggest what's missing here it would be appreciated.

**Additional Information**

This demonstration is a simplified version. In reality this code is part of a Powershell function among many other functions called by a separate script. Also the 'listings', in reality, are NUM NAME address occupations. There are no 'one' or 'two' to differentiate between them.

The issue is: that I feel I'm close to the solution. The following image shows that I can access the second listing using the `$` in regex101. My code shows I can access the first listing via `Matches[0]`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way this could be done, using a combination of [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#split-and-join-operators) and [`Group-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2):

```bash
$result = (Get-Content shortListings.txt -Raw) -split '\s*(?=\d{3})' -ne '' |
    Group-Object { [regex]::Match($_, '\w+$').Value } -AsHashTable -AsString
```

However using this method, the [Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.values?view=net-6.0#system-collections-hashtable-values) of the Hashtable would be an array of strings instead of a single string. You can however [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-7.2) them later:

```
PS ..\pwsh> $result

Name                 Value
----                 -----
one                  {001 First in listing one, 002 Second...
two                  {001 First in listing two, 002 Second...

PS ..\pwsh> $result['one']

001 First in listing one
002 Second in listing one
003 Third in listing one

PS ..\pwsh> $result['one'] -join ' '

001 First in listing one 002 Second in listing one 003 Third in listing one
```

Comment: Thank you @Santiago. This is helpful. I am trying to understand your answer. There may be a problem due to my example file `shortListings.txt` containing a simplified version of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Without the real example of how the string looks it's hard to help @Dave my answer was 100% pointed towards solving the problem using the example shown in your question.

Comment: Santiago, when you begin an answer with "Here is one way this could be done ..." I think you are providing a solution rather than an answer.  I appreciate your way is a valid approach. However I began by saying I could not capture with a capture group. As I see it: the answer was the regex pattern & utilizing the groups property of the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
# read shortListings from file 
$listings = Get-Content -Path C:\test\test6\shortListings.txt

# regex produces 3 groups 0=complete listing 1=listings in one 2=listings in two
$regex = '(?s)(001.*?)(?=001.*?)(001.*?$)'

# access group matches using array $line
[string[]]$line = $null
$line = $listings | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern $regex | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.groups}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $line.Count; $i++) {
    if ($i -eq 0) {
        # do nothing for complete listings
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "group:"$i $line[$i]
    }
   
}
```

Output:

```
group: 1 001 First in listing one 002 Second in listing one 003 Third in listing one 
group: 2 001 First in listing two 002 Second in listing two 003 Third in listing two
```